# HTTPS security in Tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat7

I am currently exploring out security in Tomcat and I just have one item that I don't get, or maybe I am missing a basic HTTP concept.

In the example project in Tomcat, I already configured SSL security like this
and then created my own certificate.

```
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/security/protected/*</url-pattern>
    ......
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
    ......
  </auth-constraint>
  <!-- must use SSL for secure transport -->
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

All is working fine and whenever I access a secured resource I am being redirected to https.

Now I was testing this locally and I am using Google Chrome Dev Tools and
while I was exploring the Network exchanges, I still see that my user name and password are still passed as plain text.  My first thought is that they would be encrypted as something

[image]

There's no issue in here right?  I can see in my network tab that my details are passed in plain text but others wont be able to see this, right?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Chrome's builtin tools to inspect the traffic it most probably shows the content before SSL-encryption takes place - you would not be able to read a single thing in that post otherwise.

If you want to see what's really "on the wire" you could capture the traffic using e.g. [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

With HTTPS the data are encrypted in the communication channel. End points are not protected. That means that output is probably before you send it, or in the other side when you receive it.